# How to reshape Data for LSTM Time Series Prediction?

Tags: time-series, lstm, reshape, forecasting

```
values = lstm_df_w.values
n_train_weeks = len(train_set_weekly_multi)
train = values[:n_train_weeks]
test = values[n_train_weeks:,:]
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
```

Hello Everyone,
at the moment i am trying to do a multivaraite Time Series Forecasting Projekt.
I managed to build a Model and to the forecast.
However it is only using 1 Timestemp of the past. But i want to try different past Time Stamps for the prediction.

If i change the value to 2 i get this error message:
cannot reshape array of size 2322 into shape (258,2,9)

Does anyone now how to deal with this problem?

Picture of the DF:
[Picture of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7NQN.png)

Comment: It would be great if you could add some example data in a dataframe in your code so that others can execute it and recreate the problem locally as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you may find [this](https://ai4water.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils/#ai4water.utils.utils.prepare_data) and [this](https://github.com/AtrCheema/Miscellaneous_DL_Tutorials/blob/master/prepare_input_data_for_rnn_for_ts_prediction.ipynb) useful which illustrate data preparation for LSTM focusing on time series

Comment: yes the following link contains a screenshoot of the DF.
https://gyazo.com/d6dc59f050b8d7af27c343536feaa022